# How to execute bash script on a remote machine asynchronously

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm stuck with an exercise. I'm writing a bash script where I need to start execution of bash script on a remote machine and then instantly continue scripts execution. I have tried using this:

`ssh user@host 'nohup bash -s > /dev/null 2>&1&' < local_script.sh`

This however seems to be doing nothing. I have searched the web and can't find answer. All help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to leave the ssh session open for this to work properly.  If the ssh session closes then the remote process looses it's stdin.  So bash won't be able to read load_script.sh before ssh closes.

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s > /dev/null 2>&1' < local_script.sh &
```

Anything else requires you to send the script first, then kick it off.

Comment: I tried it and it worked! :D Thank you so much! Does the ssh connection automatically close after script execution finishes? or is there a way to make it close when script is done?

Comment: Keep in mind that if connection goes off ( maybe you power off your client machine ), then this will not work.

Comment: @Hicks48 yes it terminates once the command is complete.  @tuxdna yeah true. The `nohup` could be added back in to fix that.